# Simplest way to get a random military time in ruby?

Tags: ruby, datetime

I'm looking for something like
    `Time.sample`
    `=> 21:06`

Is there a way to get this without defining a custom method?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Your question isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow. Where did you search, and what did you find and why didn't that help? Did you write code? If not, why? If so, where is the minimum code that demonstrates a specific problem you encountered?

Comment: I think you mean `0..23` ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would start with something like this:

```
minutes = rand(1440)
[minutes / 60, minutes % 60].map { |part| part.to_s.ljust(2, '0') }.join
#=> 0957
```

Comment: Could not resist golfing: `"%02d%02d" % rand(1440).divmod(60)`

Answer (score 0):

A datetime object can't be formatted in any sort of way; if you want it to look a particular way, you have to convert it to a string. I ended up just using the Faker gem:

`Faker::Time.between(1.days.ago, Date.today, :all).strftime("%H:%M")`